# How to use an AudioProfile with an Expression Encoder Job

Tags: c#, expression-encoder

I'm trying to encode a WMA10 file, but need to set the VBR Quality.

```
private void Encode()
{
    MediaItem mediaItem;
    mediaItem = new MediaItem(this.fileNameToEncode);

    using (Job job = new Job())
    {
        WmaAudioProfile wmaProfile = new WmaAudioProfile();
        wmaProfile.BitsPerSample = 24;
        wmaProfile.Channels = 2;
        wmaProfile.Codec = AudioCodec.WmaProfessional;
        wmaProfile.SamplesPerSecond = 44100;

        VariableQualityBitrate vbrQuality = new VariableQualityBitrate(98);
        wmaProfile.Bitrate = vbrQuality;

        //Now that I have my profile setup
        //how can I use it?

        job.MediaItems.Add(mediaItem);
        job.OutputDirectory = @"D:\temp\";
        job.Encode();
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to actually apply a [AudioProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.profiles.wmaaudioprofile%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to a [Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.job%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place. The profile gets applied to the MediaItem instead.

`mediaItem.OutputFormat.AudioProfile = wmaProfile;`